# Mongoose delete multiple data at once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a big list of ids that I want to delete from mongodb from multiple models, the main idea is that I have the same id for a document in multiple schemas and I would like to delete a document from each model. I am doing it like this:

```
_.each(wrongList, function(item) {
        UPUSTP.find({id: item.id}).remove(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log("Error while deleting " + err.message);
        })

        UPUANAM.find({id: item.id}).remove(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log("Error while deleting " + err.message);
        })

        UPUEXE.find({id: item.id}).remove(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log("Error while deleting " + err.message);
        })

        UPUEXO.find({id: item.id}).remove(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log("Error while deleting " + err.message);
        })

        UPUPROC.find({id: item.id}).remove(function(err) {
            if (err)
                console.log("Error while deleting " + err.message);
        })
    })
```

The problem is that I have 14000+ ids in the `wrongList` and the query works but it takes a lot of time to finish... how can I increase the time of the remove? Can I remove in batch or something like that?

Answer (score 24):

I think that you could use $in operator of mongodb.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Something like:

```
UTUSTP.remove({_id: {$in: wronglist}}, function(){...}); // and so on
```

Answer (score 17):

Assuming that you're using `lo-dash`, you can get a collection of `item` ids with the`_.pluck` function. Let's call it `idsArray`.
Now you could use of the `$in` operator, in an [`async.parallel`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#parallel) call, using `remove` directly from your models, like:

```
async.parallel({
  function (callback) {
    UPUSTP.remove({ id: { $in: idsArray } }, function (err) {
      if (err) return callback("Error while deleting " + err.message);
      callback(null, "Some useful message here...");
    });
  },
  . // do the same with the other collections
  .
  .
  function (err, result) {
    // check the error and do somethin useful with the results
  }
```

First, the `$in` will reduce the db calls to one per collection. Then the `async.parallel` will run the tasks in parallel and last, the `remove` directly from the model will remove the `find` operation for each collection.